# F# String to int conversion

Tags: string, f#, integer

How do i convert from string to int in F#?

As an example i'd like to pass 
`let someString = "123` to `let someInt = 123`
I cant really find any parse methods that work for me..
This question is not about parsing from int to String, but string to int. Not duplicate of a related question.
Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Comment: The easiest way is to just use the `int` function. Apart from that, everything that works elsewhere in .NET is valid in F# as well, such as `System.Int32.Parse()`.

Comment: Whilst this question is definitely a duplicate, who picked the python question?

Comment: "This question is not about parsing from into to String" <- you don't "parse" an `int` to a `string`, you parse a `string` to `int`

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Try built-in `int` function.

```
let someString = "123" 
let someInt = someString |> int // someInt now contains 123 int value
```